Using Enver with JPA for auditing by partial update queries
I have read a lot of answers which states that I need to use JPA methods or hibernate entity manager to update tables for enver to capture the queries. But in my case there are scenarios like updating status field of a table. If I use JPA's save method I would call save and update the whole table. But I thought of writing a JPQL query with @Query annotation UPDATE entity d SET d.status = :statusvalue. But when I read through docs I what Iam understanding is enver won't capture this query call.
Is there anyway I can update only the status field without updating the whole table?
